# Get the available URL Schemes handled by a given Android Application

Tags: android, android-manifest, url-scheme

I have a suite of apps that each define different url schemes.  I have a helper app that launches my various apps with various configurations.  Right now I'm trying to test out the recently added url scheme feature.  So, given a known application on the local device (e.g. I have the package name, I have the List[ResolveInfo], I have the PackageInfo, etc...) is it possible for me to extract the url schemes that it supports?

Taking facebook as an example, if I have the package name "com.facebook.katana" is it possible for me to get from the Android OS, that the url scheme "fb://" is supported by this application?

As a side note, yes I can create a local mapping between my known package names and url schemes, but I wanted to see if a programmatic approach were possible.

Adding the definition of one of my app's activities with a url scheme defined on it:

```
<activity
    android:name="com.mycompany.activity.HandleURIActivity"
    android:exported="true">
    <!-- URL Scheme -->
    <intent-filter>
        <data android:scheme="@string/app_url_scheme" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Strings.xml

```
<string name="app_url_scheme">ac-dc</string>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this should do the trick (not tested):

```
PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
Intent i = new Intent();
i.setPackage(MY_PACKAGE);
List<ResolveInfo> list = pm.queryIntentActivities(i, PackageManager.MATCH_ALL);
for (ResolveInfo info : list) {
    Iterator<String> it = info.filter.schemesIterator();
    // iterate it to get the list of schemes.
}
```

Comment: The Activity with the intent with the scheme defined does not appear in the List of ResolveInfo.  My other Activities with other types of intent filters appear.

Comment: add android:exported="true" on that activity, see https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#exported

Comment: exported="true" didn't seem to work.  I've added my activity definition from the app's manifest I'm trying to see inside of